# Installation of MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04 - Authentication Issue

Tags: software-installation

During the last step of installation of MySQL in Ubuntu 18.04 ITS generating a error

```
ERROR **1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**
```

please help me out with possible solution

Answer (score 0):

The only 2 issues I see here are

- 'user'@'localhost'

I expect here to see a name you created and not "user". 
But in case that is what you picked then ...

- (using password: YES)

the only other problem it could be is a wrong password.

But these assume you try to connect after installing mysql. Please explain what you meant with

> During the last step of installation of MySQL

as I do not remember -installing- mysql with `apt install` tries to connect to the installed mysql. Did you use a 3rd party script?

---

Tests:

I don't have a user "test":

```
$ mysql -u test -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

---

Correct user, wrong password:

$ mysql -u rinzwind -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rinzwind'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

---

When there is no mysql installed:

```
$ ps -ef | grep mysql
$ mysql -u test -p
The program 'mysql' can be found in the following packages:
 * mysql-client-core-5.7
 * mariadb-client-core-10.0
Ask your administrator to install one of them
```